# Update Banner Text dynamically in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, cart, promotional-banner

I have a FreeShipping banner in every pate after Top of the Page after mega menu.
FreeShipping banner text will change based on customer cart specific items amount and customer group.
For this, I have written some logic, but it's not working for me.

For this, I have written the below code.

```
$customerGroupId = $block->getCustomerGroup();

$cartCount = count($block->getCustomerQuoteItems());

 if($cartCount > 0){

 $totalShipperAmount = $block->getTotalAmountOfShipperHQ($block->getCustomerQuoteItems());
  if($customerGroupId == 0){

                $notLoggedAmount = $block->getSSNotLoggedAmount();
                $totalAmount  = $notLoggedAmount - $totalShipperAmount;
                if($totalAmount  >= $notLoggedAmount){
                    $isSuperSaverValid = true;
                    $superSaverText = $block->getSSNotLoggedText();
                }else{
                    echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('Guest_Free_Shipping_Banner')->toHtml(); //static free shipping banner
                }

            }elseif ($customerGroupId == 1){

                $notLoggedAmount = $block->getSSRetailAmount();
                $totalAmount  = $notLoggedAmount - $totalShipperAmount;
                if($totalAmount  >= $notLoggedAmount){
                    $isSuperSaverValid = true;
                    $superSaverText = $block->getSSRetailText();
                }else{
                    echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('Retail_Free_Shipping_Banner')->toHtml();//static free shipping banner
                }

            }     
}
```

//Banner Design

```
if($isSuperSaverValid || $isSuperSaverValid == true && $isSuperSaver){ ?>

    <div class="freesh-banner">
        <div class=container style="padding:0px;">
            <div class="homepage-bar" style="background-color:#ffffff;border:1px solid #e1e1e1;margin:0 0 20px 0;border-radius:5px;">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12" id="freesh" style="text-align:center">
                        <div class="text-area" ><h3 style="font-size:2em;display:inline;"><?php echo $superSaverText ?></h3>
                        </div>
                        <a href="<?php echo $block->getBaseUrl() . 'freeshipping' ?>" style="text-decoration: underline;font-size:.75em;color:gray; float:right;margin-right:10px;">details</a>
                    </div>
                    <hr class="divide">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<?php } ?>
```

[image]
Created a Static block for this module and added this to Widget with the condition **After Page Header Top**.

[image]

It's working when static block, After updated with the condition it's not working. When I debug the module cart items are not getting when the page loading.

Could you please suggest us how to update the banner text dynamically when any page loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you tried to get Cart items `$block->getCustomerQuoteItems()` using Checkout session.

Your code `$block->getCustomerQuoteItems()` **does  not give right data** when FPC cache enable at your system. Will be right cart details  on ***non -cacheable pages like cart & checkout,my account pages etc***.

At Magento for getting right cart data/ Customer data you have used to [Private content](http://thttps://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/cache/page-caching/private-content.html) Or you have **to makes pages non-cacheable**.
Make home page, Category, product pages are not good ideas.

In this case, there are two solutions:

- **Whole Punching on Layout/Depersonalize** and get Customr data at your block.See more details at https://sohel.dev/2017/05/05/how-to-get-customer-id-from-block-when-full-page-cache-enable-in-magento-2/ or https://inviqa.com/blog/how-full-page-cache-works-magento-2
- Use render your banner section using knockout js &  private Content like Cart & Customer data https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/cache/page-caching/private-content.html

Comment: I have specified `cacheable="false"` in layout xml file. Still not getting any results. Any suggestion/example to get the cart items? on this scenario

Comment: Amit, any chance to look on to it?.

Comment: little but busy now. able to check after 1hrs

Comment: Okay, Thank you.